# Error shows up when trying fetch data from Firebase using axios

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

I am trying to build a web application using react. I want to fetch data from Firebase using axios but upon using the get method and passing the link into the get method I get the following error.

> localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https‍://console.firebase#########base/data/' (redirected from 'https‍://#################firebaseio.com/') from origin 'http‍://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Let me know if more information is required.

here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/aux';
import Classes from './body.css';
import Logo from '../../assets/image/Logo.png';
import Tank from './tank/tank';
import TankDetail from './TankDetail/TankDetail';
import axios from 'axios';

class body extends Component{

    state={
        percentage:0
    }

    watermeterHandler=(info)=>{
        let num= info;
        let result=Number(((100/90)*num).toPrecision(2))
        this.setState({
            percentage: result
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        axios.get('https://dista#################.com/')
        .then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            //this.watermeterHandler(response.data);
        })
    }



    render(){
        return(
        <Aux>
            <div className={Classes.upperBody}>
                <img src={Logo} alt='hi'/>
                <h1>" Make Every Drop of Water Count "</h1>
                <button onClick={this.props.scroll}>Start Conservation</button>
            </div>
            <div className={Classes.lowerBody}>

                <div className={Classes.tankBody}>
                    <Tank percent={this.state.percentage}/> 
                </div>
                <div className={Classes.tankDetail}>
                    <TankDetail dataDetail={this.state.percentage}/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </Aux>

    );
    }
}



export default body;
```

Comment: without some code in we can only guess which is not going to be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add .json to the link set as parameter in the get function. This will eliminate the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add .json at end of the link or to the parameter to be precise. This will end the error